# Search for keywords send preceeding text to specific textboxes vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a txt text file in that I have a few lines as follows:

```
SW1:bla bla bla
SW2:yada yada yada
SW3:yak yak yak
```

I would like vb net to look for the line SW1: and place whatever preceeds in textbox1
like wise sw2: in textbox2, and SW3: in textbox 3:

all the remaining lines go in rich textbox1

is it possible to search for key words and send the preceeding text to specific textboxes ussing vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usee `File.ReadAllLines` to load the entire file into an array of strings (one item per line in the file).  Then, you can use the `String.StartsWith` and `String.SubString` methods to parse each line, for instance:

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    If line.StartsWith("SW1:") Then
        TextBox1.Text = line.SubString(4)
    End If
    '...
Next
```

Alternatively, if all the keywords are the same length, you could use a select case:

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    Select Case line.SubString(0, 4)
        Case "SW1:"
            TextBox1.Text = line.SubString(4)
        ' ...
    End Select
Next
```

Or, if all the keywords end with a colon, and none of the values contain that character, you could use `String.Split` to split the key/value pair from each line:

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    Dim parts() As String = line.Split(":"c)
    Select Case parts(0)
        Case "SW1"
            TextBox1.Text = parts(1)
        ' ...
    End Select
Next
```

To read the rest of the file into a rich text box, there are multiple ways you could do that, but one of the simplest ways would be like this:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    If line.StartsWith("SW1:") Then
        TextBox1.Text = line.SubString(4)
    Else If line.StartsWith("SW2:") Then
        TextBox2.Text = line.SubString(4)
    Else If line.StartsWith("SW3:") Then
        TextBox3.Text = line.SubString(4)
    Else
        builder.AppendLine(line)
    End If
Next
RichTextBox1.Text = builder.ToString()
```

Comment: Ussed the first option works like a charm, didnt think it would be as simple and effective as that wow!

Comment: One question though remains how do I read the remainder of the file into a rich textbox (thats everything except lines SW1: SW2: and SW3:?

Comment: I will have to test this 2 morrow its beer o'clock now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since Mr. Steven already got the answer. You can also use like this,.

```
Dim source = File.ReadAllLines("d:\source.txt")
sw1TextBox.Text = source.Where(Function(c) c.StartsWith("SW1:")).FirstOrDefault().Substring(4)
sw2TextBox.Text = source.Where(Function(c) c.StartsWith("SW2:")).FirstOrDefault().Substring(4)
sw3TextBox.Text = source.Where(Function(c) c.StartsWith("SW3:")).FirstOrDefault().Substring(4)
```

Comment: That does work, but would reload the entire file each time and would re-loop through the array multiple times, so it's not the most efficient method.

Comment: i will try a alternative solution again `:D`

Comment: @StevenDoggart, how about now sir?

Comment: +1 That's certainly much better.  It will still search through the array three separate times, but as long as the file doesn't have many lines, I'm sure that's more than acceptable.